# Msgbox Icons not working within excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently finalising the presentation of an excel reporting toolkit, and a function I have used many time previously appears to have stopped working, being the icons within a msgbox in vba.

```
MsgBox "File saved to desktop as file titled:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
filename & ".xlsx", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Information"
```

Above has been formatted across two lines, but in my file is a single line/

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this will not work.

I have tried alternatives including:

```
MsgBox Prompt:="Test", _
Buttons:=vbInformation, _
Title:="Information"
```

Regardless of the buttons (with or without define) and regardless of the type of icon sought (critical, information, question, exclamation), no icon will appear.

Am I going crazy or have I missed something basic here?

Comment: It works for me. I can see the icons

Comment: Hmm, must be a local issue. Thank for you testing!

Comment: **1.** Close Excel completely. Check Task Manager to ensure that **2.** Open a new blank excel and in the Immediate window try this `msgbox "test",vbCritical`. Do you see the icons? If no then Maybe some add-in is interferring or you may need to re-install Ms office.

Comment: My excel is heavy modified and scaled back due to use of actuarial tables and webscraping, so its likely that my work may have removed the icons as part of the modification. Thats fine, i'll create a userform for a not dissimilar effect. Thanks for looking.

Comment: Did you test what I suggested in a new file?

Comment: Maybe you are running short on memory?

Comment: Tested it on a new terminal without modifications and then retested on my instance, appears that all icons, shapes etc have been removed from my excel version for speed reasons.